# Какую роль играют кл. слова default и static при объявлении методов в интерфейсах?

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

Какие имеют отличия кл. слова default и static?

Answer (score 5):

В Java 8 стало возможным добавлять реализацию методов в интерфейсах! Что бы это сделать, перед методом нужно поставить ключевое слово default или static. В интерфейсах можно, напомню, использовать только модификатор доступа public.

Появилось кл. слово default — реализация нестатического метода в интерфейсе. Его можно переписать, если нужно, в реализующих этот интерфейс классах. Также его можно объявить абстрактным в промежуточном абстрактном классе или интерфейсе:

```
interface ourInterface{
    public default double getS(double r){
        return 2*Math.PI*r*r;
    }
}
abstract class newAbstr implements ourInterface{
    @Override
    public abstract double getS(double r);
}
interface anotherInterface extends ourInterface{
    @Override
    public double getS(double r);
}
```

Метод с кл. словом static — реализация статического метода в интерфейсе. Мы не можем переписать такой метод, так как он вызывается ТОЛЬКО через имя интерфейса. Именно поэтому реализующий класс может создать такой же по имени и списку параметров метод.

```
interface myInterface{
    public static double getS(double r){
        return 2*Math.PI*r*r;
    }
}
class myClass implements myInterface{
    public static double getS(double a){
        return a*a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new myClass().getS(2));//выведет 4
        System.out.println(myInterface.getS(2));//выведет ~25
    }
}
```